# Where to stick the configuration of Custom Provider in ASP.NET that implements ProviderBase?

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I am trying to figure out a small dillema. I have a piece of functionality that is not supported by the SqlMembership, SqlRole, and SqlProfile providers. The requirements call for using the EF, and also multiple custom features within both the Membership and Role providers.

More over I have the need to add a 4th provider to the mix - One that manages User - to - group membership.

So the question here is:

1. Add the code for group membership in the Role provider.

-- or --

1. Add the code for group membership to its own GroupProvider inheriting directly from ProviderBase.

I am leaning more towards #2, however there are a few considerations to iron out:

1. How to provide configuration settings to the GroupProvider? - I know i can potentially use a custom section in my web.config, however I wanted to add it under the `<system.web>` section along side the Role, Membership, and Profile providers.
2. When in the execution life-cycle of the provider do the `public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)` fires? What causes this to be executed?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i couldn't find any info on this so I decided to stick my custom code into the RoleProvider. Accessing the custom functions of the RoleProvider is as simple as:

```
string providerName = "MyProvider";
CustomRolesProvider provider = Roles.Providers[providerName] as CustomRolesProvider;
```

Whenever the provider is accessed it fires the `Initialize` event if it is not yet initialized - which reads the config settings from the `Web.Config` under the `System.Web section`